# UIFont Helvetica-Regular font issue

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uifont

I need to create UIFont with Helvetica-Regular, I use this code:

```
UIFont *font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica-Regular" size:size];
```

But font is nill.
How to do that correctly?

Comment: May be useful: http://iosfonts.com/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well you can view the list of fonts supported by iOS [here](http://iosfonts.com/) . The font **Helvetica Regular** does not feature in this list. If you want to go for this font name specifically then you would have to add this as a custom font.  Or you could simply use the **Helvetica** font name. To go for the custom fonts you could browse through these links :-

[How to use custom fonts in iPhone SDK?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14376941/how-to-use-custom-fonts-in-iphone-sdk)

[How to include and use new fonts in iPhone SDK?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4969329/how-to-include-and-use-new-fonts-in-iphone-sdk)

Answer (score 5):

There is no font name as `Helvetica-regular`

You can use form following

```
Helvetica
Helvetica-Bold
Helvetica-BoldOblique
Helvetica-Light
Helvetica-LightOblique
Helvetica-Oblique
```

Answer (score 4):

The Debugger helps to find the types of font available :-

```
(lldb) po [UIFont fontNamesForFamilyName:@"Helvetica"]

(id) $1 = 0x079d8670 <__NSCFArray 0x79d8670>(
Helvetica
Helvetica-Bold
Helvetica-BoldOblique
Helvetica-Light
Helvetica-LightOblique
Helvetica-Oblique
    )
```

So,you can try for anyone of them.

Courtesy :- https://stackoverflow.com/a/11741389/1865424

Answer (score 1):

Helvetica-Regular is not there as font name in iOS. For more details for font names check [this link](http://iosfonts.com/) with iOS versionwise.

Answer (score 0):

`UIFont *font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:size];`

To discover all available Fonts and their names:

```
+(void)dumpDescriptionOfAllAvailableFonts {

    NSMutableArray *allFonts = [NSMutableArray array];
    NSLog(@"%d font families", [[UIFont familyNames] count]);
    for(NSString *familyName in [UIFont familyNames]) {
        for(NSString *fontName in [UIFont fontNamesForFamilyName:familyName]) {
            [allFonts addObject:fontName];
        }
    }

    NSLog(@"%d fonts", [allFonts count]);

    for(NSString *fontName in [allFonts sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:@[[NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"description" ascending:YES]]]) {
        NSLog(@"%@",[fontName description]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can log all of the available styles for a particular font family like this:

```
NSLog(@"%@", [UIFont fontNamesForFamilyName:@"Helvetica"]) ;
```

>

```
FontTest[41050:c07] (
    "Helvetica-LightOblique",
    Helvetica,
    "Helvetica-Oblique",
    "Helvetica-BoldOblique",
    "Helvetica-Bold",
    "Helvetica-Light"
)
```

You are probably after staight "Helvetica"...